# See how much memory my program used in Terminal

Tags: linux, memory-management, terminal, runtime

I know when I type `time ./myProgram <input.txt >output.txt`  on the terminal, once my program finish running, I can see the runtime conveniently. There must be some similar command to see memory usage of the program right? Please inform me concisely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to tell how much memory the terminal is using at any one *time* is to use `top` and:

- find the line that corresponds to the terminal's process.
- find the column that corresponds to memory usage (`man top` could likely tell you -- I'm on a Windows machine right now, and can't easily look it up.)

Perhaps try this command:

`top | grep terminal`

('terminal' can be replaced with 'xterm' or whatever terminal program you use)

Again, this will tell you the memory usage of a program *at a particular time*.